# Using Media constructor to read from .NET stream

Tags: .net, stream, h.264, libvlcsharp

We are using Media constructor to create media from buffer (C# .NET memory stream) but no video is displayed

**_mediaPlayer.Play(new Media(_libVLC, buffer, "--demux h264"));**

Our stream works perfectly when testing with standalone VLC windows app where we need to specify h264 demuxer (--demux h264) to get video decoded properly, so we assume we need to specify demux to libVLC  in a similar way, but we can't find how to pass such options the proper way.
Maybe some other options will have to be passed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`new LibVLC("--demux=h264")`

Answer (score 0):

The API has changed recently, there is a new `MediaInput` class (and a `StreamMediaInput` implementation) that can be passed into the constructor, see [the source code](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/blob/3.x/LibVLCSharp/Shared/Media.cs#L240).

This API has a way to pass media arguments:
try:

```cs
new Media(libVLC, mediaInput, ":demux=h264")
```

Note:

- use `:option` instead of `--`
- Don't separate option name from value with a space within the same string. either use `=` or split them in two arguments (`":demux", "h264"`)